# What is The difference between ListBox and ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-listview

What is the difference between WPF's ListBox and ListView? I can not find any significant difference in their properties. Is there different typical use?

Comment: Not mentioned in answers: `ListView` has column headers, `ListBox` does not

Answer (score 269, accepted):

A `ListView` is basically like a `ListBox` (and inherits from it), but it also has a `View` property. This property allows you to specify a predefined way of displaying the items. The only predefined view in the BCL ([Base Class Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)#Base_Class_Library)) is `GridView`, but you can easily [create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx).

Another difference is the default selection mode: it's `Single` for a `ListBox`, but `Extended` for a `ListView`

Answer (score 48):

A `ListView` let you define a set of `views` for it and gives you a native way (`WPF` `binding` support) to control the display of `ListView` by using defined `views`.

***Example:***

***`XAML`***

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding list}" Name="listv" MouseEnter="listv_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="listv_MouseLeave">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <GridView x:Key="one">
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
            <GridView x:Key="two">                    
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="View" Value="{StaticResource one}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="View" Value="{StaticResource two}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
```

***`Code Behind:`***

```
private int viewType;

public int ViewType
{
    get { return viewType; }
    set 
    { 
        viewType = value;
        UpdateProperty("ViewType");
    }
}        

private void listv_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ViewType = 1;
}

private void listv_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ViewType = 2;
}
```

***OUTPUT:***

***Normal View: View 2 in above `XAML`***

[image: Normal]

***MouseOver View: View 1 in above `XAML`***

[image: Mouse Over]

> ***If you try to achieve above in a `ListBox`, probably you'll end up writing a lot more code for`ControlTempalate`/`ItemTemplate` of `ListBox`.***

Comment: The Code Behind section is not valid code as of 2019-04-29 (extra closing brace and UpgradeProperty). Can it be corrected?

Comment: It's already correct. UpdateProperty is  a method to notify property changed. It can be totally different for you. Use wherever method you are using to notify property changed. and which extra brace?

Comment: Well thank you for the explanation. And you are right. I guess I was mesmerized by the brace locations. There is indeed no extra braces. I will make a little code relooking though if you agree.

Answer (score 16):

Listview derives from listbox control.
One most important difference is listview uses the extended selection mode by default . listview also adds a property called view which enables you to customize the view in a richer way than a custom itemspanel.
One real life example of listview with gridview is file explorer's details view.
Listview with grid view is a less powerful data grid.
After  the introduction of datagrid control listview lost its importance.