# How to display the image beside listbox items?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, listbox

I have a `ListBox` displaying machine names. I want to display image icons beside each item in the `ListBox`, i.e. play the image beside a machine which is connected and stop the image beside the machine which is not connected.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Try to use DataGridView instead of ListView. There is a `Picture Box Column` where u can show the image.

Comment: i just have a listbox where the items are being populated from a dictionary.

Comment: But we are trying to tell you that better ways of getting what you want exists. They exist in the form of `DataGridView` or `ListView`.

Comment: ok. listview works same as a listbox but with extra features. is this what you are trying to say? @MarcusWigert

Comment: Exactly, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703641/what-is-the-difference-between-listbox-and-listview) & [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: @MarcusWigert Thanks. Let me stabilize my project architecture by changing the listbox control to a listview control. Then am getting back to you regarding the image thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/472897/3761928

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ListView` instead of `ListBox` control. It supports multiple types of columns and images as well.

Have a look at the following tutorials that will guide through the way to accomplish what you exactly need:

1. [A CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43265/ImageListView)
2. [An answer on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255579/c-sharp-net-windows-forms-listview-with-image-in-detail-view)

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please extract vital information from the links and only use them as a reference, instead of simply saying: "Go [here](http://www.example.org)."

Comment: He is not using `ListView`, I don't know how is he populating it. In this case he will have to completely change his logic related to `listbox`. So it is not a specific problem but he needs guidance to complete solution which is provided into links.

Comment: I clearly see your point and agree on it, but such guidance should be provided in the form of comments instead of as an answer.

Comment: @Shaharyar Thanks.I will refer to the links you suggested too.