# Accessing the border around a contentpresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, contentpresenter

I have a ListView which uses a DataTemplate. When an item is selected a border and background is added but I am unsure where from. This shows in the visual tree as a border around the ContentPresenter but inside the ListViewItem. The properties show that they were added by triggers in the TemplatedParent template. How can I override these triggers given the structure below or is my approach wrong?

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListview" ItemsSource="{Binding Thumbnails}"    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:VirtualizingWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" ....../>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ThumbItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ThumbItem}"> 
            <Grid Margin="6" Width="128"  Height="168">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="128"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" MaxHeight="128" MaxWidth="128" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,6,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="Description" Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </Grid>        
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: That's done by the ControlTemplate of the ListViewItem. You may override this behavior by setting the Template property in the ListViewItem Style. Besides that, unless you set the ListView's View property, you may as well use the simpler ListBox class: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4703641/1136211. If you don't want to visualize any selection state at all, use an ItemsControl.

Comment: Control Template worked perfectly thanks. Good point on using the listbox instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These come from the `ItemContainerStyle`. You could define your own custom template for the `ListViewItem`, e.g:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can copy the default template by right-clicking on a `ListBox` in design mode in Visual Studio and choose Edit Additional Templates->Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle).